# Pulling in 'like' url data from open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Just developed an app that asks for user permission and is pulling in a list of external "liked" products from a website.  So querying the open graph against the user id and identifying the URL of the product they have liked to create a list of products.  This no longer seems to be working? the URL string doesn't seem to be an option.  Does anyone know if Facebook have changed anything?

Comment: I assume you mean the Graph API rather than Open Graph? Do you have an example of the graph API URL your are requesting (obviously without access token)?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've solved your problem by now, but a similar issue has come up so I'll leave some info here for other desperate searchers.

The field you are looking for is probably "website".

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/likes?fields=website
```

I was using the "link" field for this, but over the past couple days there was a bug released by FB where the link field was no longer present in the returned link data. The bug was fixed and the link field is back, however now if you are an admin or otherwise own the thing that was liked, the link field contains a URL to a FB Page for the liked object. If you don't own the object, the URL is the same as website. It's very confusing and now I'm scared to use the website value in order to identify what has been liked because it's meaning could change.

Comment: I've created a separate post for the link/website confusion I'm having [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10357018/difference-between-link-and-website-fields-for-likes) if you're interested.